# Submitting Serialized JSON to a Servlet

Tags: json, servlets

I can successfully serialize the form and submit it to a text area in the form, but don't know how to send it to a Servlet that I have already created/defined:

```
// Prepare form for Serialize
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

// Send JSON Data to ResultSet
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        //submitting to textarea "resultset"
        //needs to submit to servlet "SftpConnTest" as defined in web.xml
        //$('#ResultSet').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));        

        //?? HOW DO I SEND TO "SftpConnTest" SERVLET instead??

       return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You mean to send data from a JavaScript app to a Java Servlet? How about doing an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)?

Comment: No, that won't really work, I'm submitting to a Java Bean via the Servlet Control Logic. Well, I guess it could work, but I already have this aligned to work this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are sending this to the servlet using an HTTP POST, you can use ajax:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault(); // prevent the default form submit behavior
        var data = $('form').serializeObject();
        $.post(
            '/',
            data,
            function(resData, status, req) {
                $('#ResultSet').text(JSON.stringify(resData));
            }
        );
    }
}
```

If the servlet is not mapped to be located at the root of the web app, replace `'SftpConnTest'` in the `$.post` function with the relative path to the servlet. For example, if the servlet is mapped to `/foo/bar/SftpConnTest`, then you should have `'/foo/bar/SftpConnTest'` instead of `'SftpConnTest'`.

See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for more information on the `$.post` function.

Comment: Thank you. That's getting close, but didn't quite work! This line "$('#ResultSet').text(JSON.stringify(data));" still submits to the text area. I've tried text(JSON.stringify(data)); but it's not submitting. SftoConnTest is defined at the root. I'm going to read the link you sent and see if I can figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: The line `$('#ResultSet').text(JSON.stringify(data))` will take the response from the servlet and put it in the text area. My apologies if that is not what you wanted to do, I assumed it was from your original question. What exactly isn't working now? I just started working on servlet stuff in the last few weeks so it's all fresh in my mind. Maybe I can help you out some more.

Comment: Thank you so much for the kindness and much needed help. I do want a response back, but the servlet submits to other bean and then sends the success/failure back to the Servlet, where I expect to send the results back to the #ResultSet Text Area. Right now what is happening is that it's not submitting to the Servlet, it's just spitting the data directly to the textarea. Here is the web.xml
    `<display-name>SftpConnTest</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SftpConnTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>comm.fxndiag.SftpConnTest</servlet-class>`
Here is the form `<form action="/" id="sftp_form">`

Comment: Can you post (1) your servlet code, (2) your `<servlet-mapping>` element in your `web.xml` file?

Comment: check my updated answer, I missed a line while writing it originally.

Comment: Still don't have it working! I've spent all day learning Servlet 3.0 API, I can submit with `getParameterMap` and name and spit the results back to the browser, but not what I need, which is I know I need jquery/ajax/json object to submit back to document.ready. I'll keep trying. thank you. @llawj

Answer (score 0):

Use following to send form data via ajax to server:

```
$.post("path/to/servlet", $("#formId").serializeArray(), function (result) {
    // do something
});
```

By the way:

`serializeArray()` will convert a form to an array, which could be used directly as the "data" param of a jquery ajax request, only element that has a `name` property in the form will be included into the data,for details please check jquery api, it's very clear there.